# NSCalendar - set own firstWeekday globally

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar

Is there possibilty to set custom firstWeekday?
Should i subclass NSCalendar ?

For now i have to set it like this in every place where i need to use NSCalendar

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
calendar.firstWeekday = [NSUserDefaultsHelper firstDayOfWeek];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a category of `NSCalendar` with a lazy instantiated variable:

```
@interface NSCalendar (WeekdayCalendar)

+ (NSCalendar *)customWeekdayCalendar;

@end

@implementation NSCalendar (WeekdayCalendar)

+ (NSCalendar *)customWeekdayCalendar
{
    static NSCalendar *customCalendar = nil;
    if (customCalendar == nil) {
        customCalendar = [self currentCalendar];
        customCalendar.firstWeekday = [NSUserDefaultsHelper firstDayOfWeek];
    }
    return customCalendar;
}

@end
```

Then you can use calendar from everywhere

```
NSCalendar *myCalendar = [NSCalendar customWeekdayCalendar];
```